# Is it possible to disable in Linux Mint the mouse 'hand' that moves windows

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

One thing that wastes a lot of time for me in Linux Mint is that often everytime I click on a window tab  to display the window, on the task bar, the mouse changes to a hand and rather than display it tries to move the tab.

Once this happens once it keeps happening over and over until I restart.

I would be happier to never move the windows tabs. Is there a way to disable this functionality in Linux Mint?

Personally if this is going to remain a problem,  I would prefer that to move a windows tab you have to hold down alt or some such action.

Comment: One things I've just tried is to instal dconf-editor and then I set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse to 30 from 8. Although the problem persists.

Comment: I've found that this is occurring when I move the mouse under a tab to the bottom of the screen and then back up over a different tab. As the mouse comes up from the bottom of the screen more often than not it turns into hand ready to drag the tab. Is this a known bug?

Comment: I'm using kernel 3.16.0-38-generic currently however this problem has been with every version that I've used over the last.. perhaps nearly a year..

Comment: There's a [bug](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/5067) filed for this, but it seems no fix has been attempted.